# Saving part of screen to file (SOIL and glReadPixels)

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I'm trying to save an image of size 5x5 pixels, read with glReadPixels into a file using SOIL.

I read the pixels:

```
int x = 400;
int y = 300;
std::vector< unsigned char* > rgbdata(4*5*5);
glReadPixels(x, y, 5, 5,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &rgbdata[0]);
```

Then I try saving the read data with SOIL's save image function

```
int save_result = SOIL_save_image
    (
    "image_patch.bmp",
    SOIL_SAVE_TYPE_BMP,
    5, 5, 4,
    rgbdata[0]
    );
```

But when trying to save the image, I get an unhandled exception.

**Solution (by Christian Rau)**

```
int x = 400;
int y = 300;
std::vector< unsigned char > rgbdata(4*5*5);
glReadPixels(x-(5/2), y-(5/2), 5, 5,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &rgbdata[0]);

int save_result = SOIL_save_image
    (
    "image_patch.bmp",
    SOIL_SAVE_TYPE_BMP,
    5, 5, 4,
    rgbdata.data()
    );
```

Comment: You're going to need to add more details...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a vector of pointers to unsigned char (`std::vector<unsigned char*>`, but what you want is just a vector to unsigned char (`std::vector<unsigned char>`).

And in the call to `SOIL_save_image` you don't have to give it `rgbdata[0]`, which would be a single unsigned char (and with your incorrect vector type an uninitialized pointer, likely resulting in some memory access error), but a pointer to the complete data and thus `rgbdata.data()` (or `&rgbdata[0]` if you don't have C++11).

Comment: Thank you. It works now, however I only get black image patches. I will post my solution, when I get it.

Comment: You forgot the *. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, made the answer much more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**Also notice :**

**GL's** default pack/unpack image **width** should be multiples of **4**,  that is to say, `width` in `glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, format, type, data)` should meet the condition `width % 4 == 0`.

If **`width % 4 != 0`**(in your case `5 % 4 != 0`), it **may** lead to unexpected results. So you also have to avoid these problems and here is the solution:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
```